# Add columns in Article view in MS Dynamics CRM 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

The **Article** entity in MS Dynamics CRM 4.0 doesn't appear to be customizable. Is there any way to add some columns to the view that shows the list of article (without doing an Advanced Find)? I'd like to see the Created By and Created On attributes in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as my understanding of the SDK's page on "Unsupported Customizations" goes, this is a supported change....although I can't say for certain.

Go to the following URL (making the necessary replacements):

http://YOURCRMSERVER/YOURORGNAME/tools/viewEditor/viewManager.aspx?id=00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001204

and modify the view to suit your needs.  Save.  From the Customize Entities grid, click Publish All.  Alternatively, you should also be able to change the View dropdown to show All Entities, select the Article entity, and click Publish.

To change some other system views, replace the id from the url above with one of the ids below:

00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001899 My Activities
00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001900 Open Activities
00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001901 Closed Activities
00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001902 All Activities
00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001903 Activities Associated View
00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001911 Homepage
00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001951 Sales Process Activities Subgrid
00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000000666100 Activities Advanced Find View
00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010002000 Associated View: Notes
00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001203 Associated View Opportunities
00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001204 Articles
00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001205 Associated View: Teams
00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001206 Associated View: Competitors
00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001207 Associated View: Business Units
00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001208 Associated View: Roles
00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001209 Articles - Manage KB Search
00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001210 Associated View: Contacts

I came across most of this helpful at icu-mscrm.blogspot.com/2005/07/customizing-activity-views.html.

Comment: Thanks very much, that worked! I just needed to use a different view GUID.

Answer (score 1):

Polshgiant's answer got me 90% of the way there, but changing that particular view didn't seem to have any effect. It's actually the **Indexed Articles** view (7ad58fad-40af-4e72-ac4e-db8c82e1e62d) that I needed to change, ie. the URL was:

http://YOURCRMSERVER/YOURORGNAME/tools/viewEditor/viewManager.aspx?id=7ad58fad-40af-4e72-ac4e-db8c82e1e62d

The following SQL query helped me find it:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.SavedQueryBase
WHERE IsCustomizable = 0 AND Name LIKE '%Article%'
```